# uri.tostring() on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

```
public class profile_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
    ImageView imageViewprofile;
    EditText editTextName;
    Uri uriProfile;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    String profileImageUrl;
    Button buttonSave;
    FirebaseAuth mauth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_activity);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        imageViewprofile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        buttonSave =findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loadUserInfo();
        imageViewprofile.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    private void loadUserInfo() {
        if(mauth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
                if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                    Glide.with(this).load(user.getPhotoUrl().toString()).into(imageViewprofile);
                }
                if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                    editTextName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"load user info chal rha hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mauth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageViewProfile:
                showImageChooser();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSave:
                saveinfo();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void saveinfo(){
        uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        if(name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.setError("Name cannot be empty!");
            editTextName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(profileImageUrl== null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User profile nalla h 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null && profileImageUrl != null){
            UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().
                    setDisplayName(name).
                    setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(profileImageUrl)).
                    build();
            user.updateProfile(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,"Profile updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        if (user==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User nalla h",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            uriProfile = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uriProfile);
                imageViewprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(){
        final StorageReference profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepic"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

        if(uriProfile != null){
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfile)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //profileImageUrl = profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            profileImageUrl = uri.toString();
                            if(profileImageUrl== null){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User profile nalla h",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,"Image upload successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });


                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

        }
    }

    private void showImageChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Profile Image"),CHOOSE_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

My aim is to load the information on the profile if it already saved. 
But it's not saving due the following:

The profileImageUrl is null but only in saveinfo method, it's getting value in uploadImageToFirebaseStorage and still it's null in saveinfo method, I have made it double sure that profilimageurl is a global variable.
I don't understand this.
I'm pretty new to firebase. Please help me out.
Here's the whole code.

Comment: It's an async process. You need to wait for the result before continuing on. When I get to a computer I can write out a more thorough solution. Essentially move the uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() call outside of the save function, then call the save function from the onSuccess callback once you have the variable set.

Comment: @zgc7009 you're right , i provided the answer , please check , and edit if you see the scope of improvement

Comment: was my answer any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zgc7009 pointed out the problem is occurring due to asynchronous call , when you call

```
 uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();
```

you assume that the method will return after uploading the image and setting a url to `profileImageUrl` but no , it returns immediately after setting your listeners, then control reaches `if(profileImageUrl== null)` which is true because the image is not uploaded yet and your listener callback is not executed to set the `profileImageUrl`

then the control reaches `if(user != null && profileImageUrl != null)` which is false for the same reason, SO NOW YOU GET IT , RIGHT?

**FIX**

if i am not wrong you want to show new user image when he changes  the profile but that only can happen when the image is uploaded that means `onSuccessLisener()` on `putFile()` is executed that means that code depends on the callback so move it in the callback .

Move the code from `saveInfo()` to `uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();` like that

private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(){
        final StorageReference profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepic"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

```
    if(uriProfile != null){
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfile)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //profileImageUrl = profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        profileImageUrl = uri.toString();

    FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().
                setDisplayName(name).
                setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(profileImageUrl)).
                build();
        user.updateProfile(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,"Profile updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    if (user==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User nalla h",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
                        Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,"Image upload successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(profile_activity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
}











**note** i removed some `if` conditions because those were guranteed to be true,you will also need to make some variable final because now those are getting used within the inner class
```

**Alternatively**

`uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();` make this method return the `UploadTak` if you do want to move code from `saveInfo` something like below

```
private Task<UploadTask> uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(){
    final StorageReference profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepic"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

    if(uriProfile != null){
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfile)
    }
}
```

Now set the listener in the `saveInfo()`

I also encourage you to break the code into methods because code now looks messy, have a good day  **Himanjli**